# PHP XML Extension: Not installed

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu, mybb

So i'm currently installing mybb and went through a very long tutorial on how to do it. The problem is when I get to the requirements check this shows up

[image]

How does one go about fixing this? I read that I may need to do

sudo apt-get install php-xml

I have done this and everything went ok but still doesn't change it to installed.

FYI: I have only been using this OS for a few days so please go nice on me :)

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver after you installed php-xml?

Comment: restarted it? I just place it in a folder and its up and running. Not sure I understand what you mean :P

Comment: I mean have you tried turning it off and on? Restarting is probably the simplest way to do this or you can type `sudo service apache2 restart` in your terminal (assuming you're using apache).

Comment: eyy it worked thanks a bunch! Learning things about this OS loads quite enjoying it too, : ) Thanks

Answer (score 101):

You're close

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Then you need to restart apache so it takes effect

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: for rhel/cent os yum install php-xml

Comment: At the time of writing, you should now be using sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-xml` works fine if you are using PHP 7.4. My guess is that this command just checks your PHP version and installs the correct package based on that

Comment: @JulesColle not really, I have php8.0 and it installs `php8.1-xml` with `apt install php-xml`. So the newest version is installed.

Answer (score 50):

Had the same problem running PHP 7.2.
I had to do the following :

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml`

Comment: Thanks , it worked for me . i just ran the following commands.

-> sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml
-> sudo service apache2 restart
->composer install

Comment: I guess this is the case for Ubuntu 18 & apache2.4.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue with commands bellow:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.3-intl

$ sudo /etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm restart
```

These commands works for me in homestead with php7.3

Comment: this is `intl` and not `xml`

Answer (score 2):

In Centos

```
 sudo yum install php-xml
```

and restart apache

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with php in windows, you can just access to the file "php.ini" located in your php instalation folder and uncomment the ";extension=xmlrpc" line deleting the ";"
("extension=xmlrpc")