# how to fix pecl install XML error PHP 5.6 in debian buster?

Tags: php, debian, pecl

I have checked all the similar issues, and attempted all the most common ways to fix this problem, but I can't seem to find a solution.

1. I have checked if the -n flag is present in my pecl command but is
   not.
2. I have restarted the server after installing php-xml , which installed correctly... but still fails.

Any `pecl install` command fails. for example:

```
pecl install redis-2.2.8
```

**this is the error I get when I try to install anything PECL on Debian 10 / PHP 5.6**

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249
XML Extension not found
[ root@menem:/home/moura022/disney/commerce-ui/dockerization56 ]$ sudo service apache2 restart
[ root@menem:/home/moura022/disney/commerce-ui/dockerization56 ]$ pecl install --ignore-errors timezonedb 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249
XML Extension not found
```

I would really appreciate your kind assistance to understand what is going on here, how I can verify my installation and fix this issue? I've been several days stuck with this at work : /

Comment: I wanted to point out here that PHP 5.6 is no longer supported and end of life date was Dec, 31 2018. I strongly suggest looking for upgrade paths to PHP7 and ultimately PHP8. Not to leave you hanging though does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793676/php-xml-extension-not-installed) get you going?

Comment: saw that post and followed each solution, none of them works.
this is the PHP version used at work, is not something I can change... trust me I would.

Comment: You could go about this in a completely different direction - https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cannot-install-pecl-phpredis-with-php-5-6.551731/#post-2228571

Comment: thanks. I wish I was able to try this but I changed my job.