# Laravel Project Installation Error using Composer

Tags: php, error-handling, composer-php, laravel-9, ubuntu-22.04

I got errors while installing laravel app using composer. I used `composer create-project laravel/laravel myApp` and my os is Ubuntu 22.04. I have totally fined installing laravel using composer until this day. I got these messages in my terminal.

[image: error-messages]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should install [php-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42704868/9193372) extension.

Comment: I already installed it

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem